# How do I know how many devices can each subnet hold and also what is a possible IP address that will be assigned to the Laptop joining

Tags: networking, security

How do I know how many devices can each subnet hold and also what is a possible IP address that will be assigned to the Laptop joining

Thank you very much

the network (marked ‘arriving DHCP client’ in the diagram):

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 4):

The /24 tells you how many bits there are used for the network; that means that you have per subnet 32-24=8 bits, or 256 addresses in the subnet. Some are reserved or typically used for a specific purpose:

- 0: network address
- 1: typically used for the gateway (but not always; in your picture it is 9)
- 255: Broadcast.

Depending on your site, there may be additional reservations. But as an absolute maximum: 256-3=253 hosts.

What IP address is given to the laptop depends on your DHCP server. It may be, that it gives-out only a specific range (e.g. 100-200), or that certain addresses are reserved for specific MAC-ID's/hostnames/... There is no way to tell without going through the DHCP server configuration.

Note that this is rather basic networking stuff.